# How to query multiple rows into a single-line string result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

Let's say we have this table named `phrases` and it has contents like so:

## `phrases`

```
+----+--------+
| id | phrase |
+----+--------+
|  1 | the    |
|  2 | quick  |
| .. | ...    |
|  8 | lazy   |
|  9 | dog    |
+----+--------+
```

**Desired result**

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| sentence                                    |
+---------------------------------------------+
| the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

What should be the query statement such that it would result into a single result string like the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) with an empty delimiter, and probably with a sort order

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(phrase , '' ORDER BY id) as sentence                                    
FROM phrases;
```